# How do i turn this serialized data into an array using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on an application using wordpress, and there's a form where the site administrator inputs info about real estate properties. One of the fields (a checkbox) returns this type of data:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:12:"Alarm System";i:1;s:7:"Balcony";i:2;s:13:"Indoor Soccer";i:3;s:8:"Intercom";}
```

I'm assuming it's a serialized type of data. But i'm not being able to convert it back to a simple array using `unserialize()`. Is there another way of doing this?

I've tried in VSCode simply putting into a string and using `unserialize()` like this and it worked just fine.

```
    $serializedData = 'a:4:{i:0;s:12:"Alarm System";i:1;s:7:"Balcony";i:2;s:13:"Indoor Soccer";i:3;s:8:"Intercom";}';

    $array = unserialize($serializedData);
    var_dump($array);
```

The code above returns this

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "Alarm System" [1]=> string(7) "Balcony" [2]=> string(13) "Indoor Soccer" [3]=> string(8) "Intercom" }
```

Which is what i expected. But in the wordpress plugin editor it's not working no matter what.

First i tried

```
    function showFeatures($features){
        $array = unserialize($features);
        return $array;
    }
```

The `$features` is the first serialized data i posted above, i didn't find anywhere ind the documentation for the plugin whether it adds any type of extra data to the fields that pass to the function editor. When i try it shows

> PHP Error: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 99 bytes on line 18 of the Functions Editor

and when I do `var_dump($array)` it shows a

> bool(false)

I'm using the "All export pro" plugin. Am i missing something?

Comment: I would assume that what's going into the plugin code and being passed to unserialize is either empty, or contains extra data which isn't just the serialised data. Without a [mre] of that (you've only shown us working code and data, not the problematic stuff) there's unlikely to be much we can do to help you - my best suggestion is to do some more detailed debugging of that area of your code. See also [ask] for more guidance on making an answerable question. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `$features` does not contain exactly what in `$serializedData` is. If a deserialization fails you will encounter the error you got.

Comment: _"The $features is the first serialized data i posted above"_ - that first string is **92** bytes in length, and the error message said there was an error at "offset 0 **of 99 bytes**" - so those are pretty sure _not_ the exact same value.

Comment: How can i know what's being passed into the `$features` variable? I have no ideia where those extra 7 bytes are coming from and there's no information in the plugins documentation. I tried looking in the phpmyadmin table and i think i messed everything up. This is driving me nuts